# Guzzlehttp simple request, can't find the HTML body

Tags: php, guzzle

my question is simple. I don't understand why I can't get the HTML body of this request on Guzzlehttp:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/']);
$response = $client->get('PHP');
dd($response->getBody(true));
```

The answer is:

```
   Stream {#164 ▼
  -stream: :stream {@10 ▶}
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Works for me. The type of the body seems to be GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream, but if you cast it to a string (there are several ways to do this), you will see the response.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to a string or alternatively, use the following:

```
$response->getBody()->__toString();
```

Comment: what about `(string)$response->getBody()`